# missing field and extra space after using for loop in awk

Tags: awk

I need to use an awk script to extract some information from a file.
I have a title line which has 11 field and I split it to an array called `titleList`.

```
Student Number:Name:Lab1:Lab2:Lab3:Lab4:Lab5:Lab6:Exam1:Exam2:Final
```

After finding a proper line I need to print the fields which proceeds by the titles for example if the result is :

```
92839342:Robert Bloomingdale:9:26:18:22:9:12:25:39:99
```

I must print it in this way:

```
Student Number:92839342 Name:Robert Bloomingdale Lab1:9 Lab2:26 Lab3:18
Lab4:22 Lab5:9 Lab6:12 Exam1:25 Exam2:39 Final:99
```

I use a for loop to manage it:

```
for (i=0 ;i<=NF ;i++)
{
    printf "%s %s %s %s",titleList[i],":",$i," "
}
```

everything look good except the result which has 2 problems:
first there is an extra space between each result and second the last field of the searched line is missing

```
    Student Number : 92839342  Name : Robert Bloomingdale  Lab1 : 9  Lab2 : 26
    Lab3:18  Lab4 : 22  Lab5 : 9  Lab6 : 12  Exam1 : 25  Exam2 : 39  Final
```

what should I do?
is there any problem with `\n` at the end of the search result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can correct the amount of extra whitespace between fields by correcting the `printf` statement:

```
awk -F ":" 'NR == 1 { split($0, array, FS) } NR >= 2 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s:%s ", array[i], $i; printf "\n" }' file.txt
```

Contents of `file.txt`:

```
Student Number:Name:Lab1:Lab2:Lab3:Lab4:Lab5:Lab6:Exam1:Exam2:Final
92839342:Robert Bloomingdale:9:26:18:22:9:12:25:39:99
```

Results:

```
Student Number:92839342 Name:Robert Bloomingdale Lab1:9 Lab2:26 Lab3:18 Lab4:22 Lab5:9 Lab6:12 Exam1:25 Exam2:39 Final:99
```

***EDIT:***

Also, your missing the last value because the file you're working with probably has windows newline endings. To fix this, run: `dos2unix file.txt` before running your `awk` code. Alternatively, you can set `awk`'s record separater so that it understands newline endings:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="\r\n"; FS=":" } NR == 1 { split($0, array, FS) } NR >= 2 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s:%s ", array[i], $i; printf "\n" }' file.txt
```

***EDIT:***

The above requires GNU awk, split() splits on the FS by default so no need to use that as an arg, it's common to use "next" rather than specifying opposite conditions, and it's common to use print "" instead of printf "\n" so you use the ORS setting rather than hard-coding it's value in output statements. So, the above should be tweaked to:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { RS="\r\n"; FS=":" } NR == 1 { split($0, array); next } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s:%s ", array[i], $i; print "" }' file.txt
```

Comment: extra space is fixed but I have missed the last field yet.

Comment: in the end of the printed line after "Final" I have nothing it is like this `Exam1:25 Exam2:39 Final`

Comment: I try writing a script. It seems I can not run dos2unix inside the script

Comment: @femchi: You will need to run `dos2unix` on your file first before passing it to `awk`. Please see the edit that I've made. HTH.

Comment: @miono: Thankyou for your suggestion regarding setting `RS="\r\n"`. I'm not sure why or who rejected it, but it's an excellent one. I would have accepted it! Thanks.

Comment: Just be aware you can only set RS to multiple characters (an RE) in GNU awk. In most awks only a single character can be used as the RS.